# How to dynamically generate instances of a string in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jfreechart

I'm currently working on a project for monitoring the protocols used when I capture the packets.
Also, the protocols mostly used are OSPF, ICMP and Hop-by-Hop.
I want to create a pie chart for the protocols used and I'm trying to use JFreeChart for displaying a dynamic pie chart to display the different protocols being used.
I'm currently using this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(protocol) FROM database as count ORDER BY count
```

When I'm executing this, I get this error:
[image: [Error Image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVboT.png)

Why am I getting this error? Is it a SQL error? If yes, what would be the correct query to calculate the instances and display a pie chart for the protocol instances?

Comment: Can we see the full stacktrace? Maybe some code?

Answer (score 0):

Change your query as below

```
SELECT protocol,COUNT(protocol) as [count] FROM database.tablename 
GROUP BY protocol 
ORDER BY COUNT(protocol)
```

Comment: Still not working. Shows the same error.
Is there any other way you think we can rectify the error?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the error in your query structure

`database as count` assigns the alias, in `ORDER BY count` you care actually trying to order the columns by the database

Correct query:

`SELECT COUNT(protocol) as count FROM database  ORDER BY count`

Answer (score 0):

> pie chart to display the different protocols being used

I'm guessing you're missing a `group by` (because it doesn't make sense to select count and order by count since selecting count w/o group by would only return 1 result).

```
SELECT COUNT(*), protocol
FROM table 
GROUP BY protocol
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

Comment: The image is now getting generated, thank you!
But just the background of the image is generated, but not the pie chart.
It now looks something like this:
http://imgur.com/eanwlrA
Please help me out. What do I do to display the piechart?